# checkbox toggle change without any user interaction

Tags: javascript, jquery

I  call a function in jquery for a checkbox toggle change. It works as expected.
Now I want to change this  when the box is checked show some tables else hide.
But I don't know how to modify my function.. [1]

How can I modify this ?

[1]
HTML

```
  <label class="checkbox">                     <input type="checkbox" id="toggleSequence" name="sequence_check" id="sequence_check">
```

Jquery

```
$("#toggleSequence").change(function(e){
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
        $(this).parent().next().show();

    }else{
        $(this).parent().next().hide();

    }
});
```

Comment: Post your HTML markup, also.

Comment: We need the markup for your `table` also, we should know the relation between your `checkbox` and `table` in DOM tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/909azzxn/1/)

```
$('#toggleSequence').parents('table').next().hide(); // first you need to hide it use can also use css for this

$("#toggleSequence").change(function (e) {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        alert();
        $(this).parents('table').next().show();

    } else {
        $(this).parents('table').next().hide();

    }
});
```

Comment: can simply trigger `change` right away and achieve same thing  http://jsfiddle.net/909azzxn/2/

Comment: @charlietfl   sorry i donot want to use 'change' attribute..If you checked my working code, i use change and it works fine..but now what i need is, if that checkbox is checked show the table else hide. I want to edit my existing jquery function to achieve this.

Comment: i do not want to use change() function. Im using that already

Comment: Sorry, i got it.Not sure why it is not working if i use an id for table like;  $('#toggleSequence').parents('seqTable').next().hide();

Comment: your should write this $('#toggleSequence').parents('#seqTable').next().hide()

Comment: #seqTable for id .test for class # and . is important